# Open pdf using phone gap

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova, pdf

I wan't to open a pdf file on Xcode using phone gap[corodova 1.7.0]. Is it possible ? 
I can read text files, but for pdf should I use a plugin or something ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try [child browser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser) plugin to view pdf in phonegap app.

```
function onDeviceReady() {

        var root = this;
        cb = window.plugins.childBrowser;

        if(cb != null) {
        cb.onLocationChange = function(loc){ root.locChanged(loc); };
        cb.onClose = function(){root.onCloseBrowser(); };
        cb.onOpenExternal = function(){root.onOpenExternal(); };
        cb.showWebPage("http://xyz.com/server/data/test.pdf");

        }
    }

    function onCloseBrowser() {
        console.log("onCloseBrowser!");
    }

    function locChanged(loc) {
        console.log("locChanged!");
    }

    function onOpenExternal() {
        alert("onOpenExternal!");
    }
```

Comment: hmm I added the .m, .h & .js files, then called this function, but I don't know how can I use the plugin after that .. Do you know any documentations ?

Answer (score 2):

**No need to use** plugin rigth now(cordova 2.4+)

**IFRAME** is not a solution.

**OBJECT, EMBED** is not a solution.

---

Solution

```
window.open('http://example.com/any.pdf', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

This code will open a child browser.

---

**Phonegap PDF Viewer plugin** made for local pdf files and **It fails**.

Answer (score 1):

You can open PDF's directly within iframe element.

Another option which is worth of trying - pdf.js: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

window.open("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + pdflink +" ");

This code will open the pdf in android phones

Before using this, First add phonegap.js to your HTML page

Answer (score 0):

for local pdf files use:

window.open('./any.pdf', '_blank', 'location=no');

Answer (score 0):

You could use pdf embedding using an **iframe** with the following url

If your PDF URL is `http://yourdomain.com/your_pdf_name.pdf` then you should use the following code

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://yourdomain.com/your_pdf_name.pdf&embedded=true"></iframe>
```