# How do display a PDF inside of a div-container in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, ios, pdf, cordova

I'm currently working on a Phonegap App, previously developed by another programmer.
Right now he's using the ChildBrowser plugin to display pdf documents.

Now we want to / have do display the pdf files next to another sidebar, which is why I need the pdf inside of another div instead of ChildBrowser's new window.

I tried on using pdf.js, pdfobject.js witch no success. Embedding the PDF in the html object tag worked, but I could not scroll it. Are there any hints out there I might have missed?

Comment: Embedding the PDF into a div with fixed height and width, then you should have a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post will solve your problem.

[Open pdf using phone gap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10481904/1853864)

It explains how you use child browser plugin to view pdf file but you need use child browser to [Android](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser) and other to [iOS](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using pds.js to render PDF in HTML5: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js
Alternatively, embed pdf as iframe or object: [PhoneGap Inline PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687089/phonegap-inline-pdf/25844297#25844297)