# PhoneGap Inline PDF

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, cordova

I am having some issues getting PDFs to display inline in PhoneGap. Right now, I am loading the PDF into an Object and then trying (and failing) to set the object dimensions to the window height so it's displayed full-height (with app header and back button).

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function jqUpdateSize(){
    var pixels = $(window).height();

    pixels = pixels - 48;

    $('#pdfViewer').height(pixels);
};
$(document).ready(jqUpdateSize)
$(window).resize(jqUpdateSize); 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="content" style="padding:0px; height:auto;">
    <object width="100%" height="100%" data="file.PDF"></object>
</div>
```

This partially works (it works PERFECTLY in Chrome/FF on my desktop) but fails miserably and doesn't work in-app on both Android and iOS.

I saw some documentation about a plugin "ChildBrowser", but I'm not sure it will do what I want or how I would go about getting it setup.

Comment: As android browser cannot render pdf files,it will not work in android browser..in ios u can show it using iframe

Comment: Won't I have the same height problem with an iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

you should try adding iframe instead of object..

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="file.PDF">   
</iframe >
```

Comment: Great, but how can I have it dynamically resize based on the device? eg. that may work for the iPhone, but not the iPad.

Comment: Thanks, but the Height % doesn't work on either desktop or mobile (width does though).

Comment: U ll have to make html and body in 100% width n height first

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using pdf.js to render PDF: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js