# Open pdf in Android Mobile using IBM Worklight studio

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to open a pdf in android mobile device. 
For that ,I have add a 'test.pdf' pdf file in common folder and add plugin (Childbrowser ) in config.xml file (res/xml/config.xml). And again add childbrowser.js and cordova.js file in js folder .

And add a code to open a pdf file here---
window.open('./test.pdf','_system','location=yes');
But still exception is coming like that 'Target file is not available' andgive a path 
file.///data/data/
I want to load that test.pdf file in the android mobile and open that particular file . 
But it is not opening .
Please suggest me a solution. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at these questions:

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155466/open-pdf-using-jquery-mobile
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444333/ibm-worklight-app-common-pdf-file-access

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Android does not support viewing PDFs out of the box in a WebView. Most results point to using Google Docs.

Here are some suggestions:

- [Open PDF in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434487/open-pdf-in-a-webview)
- [How to open local pdf file in webview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613505/how-to-open-local-pdf-file-in-webview-in-android)
- http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/147570/open-remote-pdf-file-on-webview-in-android
- This you could do by combining a Cordova plug-in and this native code: http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Loading-PDF-in-Android-WebView
- http://asmncl.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/android-open-pdf-file-in-webview.html